# The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to do some adding and deleting of quick launch nodes on a SharePoint site, but I am getting this error when trying to reach child nodes from a certain node. Here is my code as of right now:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url $SiteMenu -Credentials $cred
$nodes = Get-PnPNavigationNode

foreach($node in $nodes){

    if($node.title -eq "Opportunities"){
        $children = $node.Children

        foreach($child in $children){
            Write-Host $child.title
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exact error I get.

```
The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request 
has not been executed. It may need 
to be explicitly requested.

At C:\Users\ahosek\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.ps1:18 char:17

+         foreach($child in $children){
+                 ~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials
$nodes = Get-PnPNavigationNode

foreach($node in $nodes){

    if($node.title -eq "Opportunities"){
        $oppNode = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id $node.Id 
        $children = $oppNode.children
        foreach($child in $children){
            Write-Host $child.title
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials
$nodes = Get-PnPNavigationNode

foreach($node in $nodes){


    if($node.title -eq "Opportunities"){
        #$children = $node.Children
        $children = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Id $node.Id 
        foreach($child in $children){
            Write-Host $child.title
        }
    }
}
```